# Codeigniter database date-compare

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, date

Im having a problem comparing dates in a database to a week from now using activerecord. I'm trying to return a list of events with their start date less than a week from now.

The event_start_date is in the format of 2011-06-30 09:00:00

```
$this->db->select('event_id,title,event_start_date,location');
$this->db->where('event_start_date <=',DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAYS ));
$query = $this->db->get('sd_events');
```

Having trouble working out the right syntax for this, any help would be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things. First, have you tried putting your where clause in quotes like this:

```
$this->db->where('event_start_date <=','DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAYS )');
```

Second, if necessary just skip using the where function and put the entire query in like this:

```
$this->db->query('SELECT event_id,title,event_start_date,location FROM sd_events WHERE event_start_date <= DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAYS )');
```

Comment: Yeah i ended up just writing in one big query and did it that way, its a shame as breaking it down in to seperate lines makes it so much easier to read.

Comment: What's with the hateof using where()? Is it due to slow code?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the first argument to do accept functions with the ->where.

```
$this->db->select('event_id,title,event_start_date,location');
$this->db->where('event_start_date <= DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAYS)', null);
$query = $this->db->get('sd_events');
```

This should put it in your WHERE statement just asis. Otherwise, it'll wrap your "DATE_ADD" in single quotes which doesn't evaluate.